# PHP, set bounce back email address

Tags: php, email

When using PHP to send email, how can I set the return path for receiving bounced back emails?

Comment: Check out my similar question with several good responses. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965986/preventing-delivery-status-notification-errors-or-email-replys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965986/preventing-delivery-status-notification-errors-or-email-replys)

Answer (score 4):

There is a parameter in `mail()` that allows user to set additional headers. You should set a "Return-Path" header, like this:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message,
"From: $returnaddress\n"
. "Reply-To: $returnaddress\n"
. "Return-Path: $returnaddress");
```

Answer (score 4):

To get this to work on my server (bluehost) I had to also use the fifth parameter (i.e. "$additional") as shown below:

```
     $headers = "From: joe.smith@shaw.ca\r\nReply-To: joe.smith@shaw.ca";

     $additional = "-rjoe.smith@shaw.ca";

     mail("fred.jones@shaw.ca", "Subject", "Message",$headers, $additional);
```